# Bizarre IE behavior with sample code from w3schools.com

Tags: html, css

I took this code as an example from the w3schools.com sample page https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_dropdown.asp

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<style>
.dropbtn {
  background-color: #4CAF50;
  color: white;
  padding: 16px;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: none;
}

.dropdown {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

.dropdown-content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  min-width: 160px;
  box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
  z-index: 1;
}

.dropdown-content a {
  color: black;
  padding: 12px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: block;
}

.dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

.dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {display: block;}

.dropdown:hover .dropbtn {background-color: #3e8e41;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Hoverable Dropdown</h2>
<p>Move the mouse over the button to open the dropdown menu.</p>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="dropbtn">Dropdown</button>
  <div class="dropdown-content">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

This code tested on the site in the test page (https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_js_dropdown_hover) works perfectly with the various browsers in my possession (Chrome, Firefox 26, Firefox 78, IE11, IE for WIN10, edge, safari, opera) and they get this

[image]

Well. I took the code I copied and pasted it on a test page on my home server and the code works perfectly with all the same browsers but not with IE11 and IE for WIN10. I get this behavior

[image]

What am I doing wrong since on the site with IE it works perfectly?

Comment: Impossible to say. W3Schools probably has some site-wide CSS that affects its samples that your code doesn't have. BTW, IE on Windows 10 is IE11.

Comment: IE should never be used. But anyway, I also found this stylesheet: https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css

Comment: There are better sites for learning HTML/CSS than w3schools.  They used to have outdated/inaccurate examples and information, I'm not really sure if they've improved in recent years.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Still bugs me that when I search they tend to come up first

Comment: @j08691 A lot of the time, I'll add `-site:www.w3schools.com` to my searches.

Comment: Can you serve your code from your server publicly, so we can reproduce your issue?

Comment: the reason that is happening is because that IE11 needs a strictness to it...meaning theres a position absolute...every modern browser understand what to do...but poor old IE11 says I don't know where to go! meaning it needs at least a `left` and `top` positioning

Comment: Thank you all,  @connexo the code is the one posted

Comment: @LuisAFK do you tell me? I haven't used windows for 25 years :))

Comment: @Riskbreaker the code and the browser are the same

Comment: @Heretic Monkey I'd really like to know what this code is :)

Comment: Well, Stack Overflow isn't a site that debugs other site's faulty CSS for free, unless that CSS is known and can be reproduced here.

Comment: @Heretic Monkey   You misunderstood me. The question is "Why does the code I posted work correctly on all browsers but not with IE11?"
The code I posted contains the CCS (as you surely have seen)